# Calling custom phonegap plugin gives error "Uncaught ReferenceError: calendar is not defined"

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am creating a phonegap test project with custom calendar plugin published [here](https://github.com/hollyschinsky/CalendarPlugin). When I call it on device ready, I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: calendar is not defined" error.
I have published the code on github. Here's [the link](https://github.com/sanjaycedti/AssociateSearch) if you want to take a look.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Finally, I had to created two separate projects for Android and iOS with separated plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code on github: in /www/index.html you are referencing `src="calendar.js"` which would assume that its path is /www/calendar.js when in fact it's located at /plugins/org.devgirl.calendar/www/calendar.js so your script tag should contain `src="../plugins/org.devgirl.calendar/www/calendar.js"`